# Places API not working. Error: You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-cloud-console

I have an Android app where I display nearby places like gas stations, pharmacies, etc. using Google Map. I am using Maps & Places API.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=12.2649519,76.6208733&radius=10000&type=hospital&sensor=true&key=MY_API_KEY

I have enabled billing for my account. I have linked the account to my project. The app was working fine. However when I check it now, it gives me error

{   "error_message" : "You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at [https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started"](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started%22),   "html_attributions" : [],   "results" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}

My billing account is active. I have not done any changes to the code nor to my billing account. I have not set any application or API restrictions on my API key.

Comment: How is this question related to Firebase?

Comment: @Alex Mamo Edited the tags

Comment: you solved this issue or not I am facing same problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced the same issue. Apparently there are two kinds of billing accounts. Google cloud and google maps platform. and I think you have used google cloud billing account. Try by linking to google maps platform billing account. I am unable to switch my billing account to google maps platform for this project for some reason so I have created another project and added this google maps platform billing account to this projects. and it works ! yay !

use this link to create google maps platform billing account
https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started

Comment: You do not need to create a new project. To switch billing, first, disable project billing, then change billing account and enable billing afterward.

Comment: For me it was the API Key. I found a mention to regenerate the API key and upon looking closer i was missing the last character from it. One would have assumed an incorrect API key error but nope, billing error. So FYI for anyone trying to follow all of these steps and coming up Millhouse.